¿Cómo aplicar CSS a un DIV padre?
Buen dia,
queria saber como aplicar CSS a un div al que no puedo darle una clase ni un ID y este contiene a otros de esta forma:


<div>
   <div id="dialogo"></div>
</div>



Lo que pasa es que tengo una web que inserta unas lineas de HTML y quiero cambiarle el CSS al DIV que contiene al otro div id="dialogo"
gracias

Para eso utilizas la pseudo clase :has, la cual te permite seleccionar un elemento basado en sus hijos
Ejemplo de seleccionar un div que tenga un hijo con id dialogo:


div{ padding:100px;}
#dialogo{ background-color:red;}

div:has(#dialogo){
  background-color:blue;
}
<div>
   <div id="dialogo"></div>
</div>



Ejemplo de seleccionar un div que tenga un hijo INMEDIATO con id dialogo:
Notar en el uso de > en div:has(>#dialogo)


div{ padding:100px;}
#dialogo{ background-color:red;}

div:has(>#dialogo){
  background-color:blue;
}
<div>
   <div id="dialogo">Soy hijo inmediato</div>
</div>

<div>
   <section>
      <div id="dialogo">No soy hijo inmediato</div>
   </section>
</div>



